# GeckoFX asking for XULAppInfo

Tags: c#, gecko

Installed GeckoFx with the latest stable (45.0.30), trying to Initialize Firefox it asks for `XULAppInfo` for the first time, then it gives me an error saying:

> System.NotImplementedException' occurred in Geckofx-Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.

The relevant code:

```
public Form1() {
    Xpcom.Initialize("FireFox");
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

The stack trace is:

```
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: permissionDBPDir
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: permissionDBPDir
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: cachePDir
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: Home
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: Desk
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: UAppData
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: AppData
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: Progs
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: WinD
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: XREAppFeat
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: XREUSysExt
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: XREAddonAppDir
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: XRESysSExtPD
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: XRESysLExtPD
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: XREAppDist
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: UAppData
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in Geckofx-Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in Geckofx-Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OutOfMemoryException' in Geckofx-Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotImplementedException' in Geckofx-Core.dll
'GeckoDraft.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: GeckoDraft.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

Comment: Is this all your code related to Gecko? Could you edit the question with the full stack trace?

Comment: Yes I just trying to start new project using the latest gecko  stable version which is: 45.0.30

Answer (score 3):

Am using vb.net and had the same problem but I fixed it. 
I just wrote following line:

```
Xpcom.EnableProfileMonitoring = False
```

and then:

```
Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox")
```

Full example:

```
Dim ss As New GeckoWebBrowser

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Xpcom.EnableProfileMonitoring = False
        Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox")
        ss.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        Me.Controls.Add(ss)
        ss.Navigate("www.google.com")
 End Sub
```

Comment: great solutions... i never knew about this but thanks... any explanation why it happened just like this?